# how can I move my whatsapp account from an old phone to another without having the old phone to verify?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I need big help please, my parents have taken my phone and there are some whatsapp chats they must not see, is there any way I can delete my whatsapp account or move it to a new number without having my sim? Or a way to delete the chats from elsewhere? 
please hurry, I don't have much time

Comment: *please hurry, I don't have much time* -- Users are volunteers here and not some 24*7 working paid employees. Please exercise patience.

Comment: Also, if you're in such a hurry: why don't you simply use [our site search](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[whatsapp-messenger]+migrate+answers%3A1), browse the [whatsapp tag](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp-messenger), or check the [WhatsApp FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/)? What efforts have *you* taken if you're in such a hurry?

Comment: I think without phone verify it is not possible to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Delete your phone remotely with Google theft service.